# How to specify columns in Swagger

Tags: yaml, markdown, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

How to specify 3 columns in a swagger editor so the output should look like:

```
a            b            c
x            y            z
```

```html
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: >
    This is a sample server Petstore server.



    [Learn about Swagger](http://swagger.io) or join the IRC channel `#swagger`
    on irc.freenode.net.



    For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the
    authorization filters

    **Here I want to specify 3 columns**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially a Markdown question. To make a table in Markdown use a tool like [this](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) or following syntax:

```
| One | Two | Three |
|-----|-----|-------|
| a   | b   | c     |
```